# Initializing static member of nested templated class during nested template specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, static

Here is my problem:

```
template<typename T>
class Outer 
{
public:
    template<typename U>
    class Inner 
    {
    private:
        static int count;
    };

    static int code;
    void print() const
    {
        std::cout << "generic";
    }
};

template<>
template<>
class Outer<bool>::Inner<bool> 
{
    static int count;
};

template<>
template<>
int Outer<bool>::Inner<bool>::count = 4; // ERROR
```

How do I initialize it properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fully-specialized templates are in fact no longer templates, so your definition should simply be:

```
int Outer<bool>::Inner<bool>::count = 4;
```

In full, with all definitions in place, your code should look like:

```
template<typename T>
class Outer 
{
public:
    template<typename U>
    class Inner 
    {
    private:
        static int count;
    };

    static int code;
    void print() const
    {
        std::cout << "generic";
    }
};

template<typename T>
int Outer<T>::code = 0;

template<typename T>
template<typename U>
int Outer<T>::Inner<U>::count = 0;

template<>
template<>
class Outer<bool>::Inner<bool> 
{
    static int count;
};

int Outer<bool>::Inner<bool>::count = 4;
```

Comment: Hi ildjarn, Pasted your code into visual studio and I'm getting following error: **error C2906: 'int Outer<T>::Inner<bool>::count' : explicit specialization requires 'template <>'**  Can you exlplain that?

Comment: @codekiddy : I tested this exact code (plus `#include <iostream>`) in VC++ 2010 SP1 without errors. It also works with [GCC 4.3.4](http://ideone.com/gvICi) and [GCC 4.5.1](http://ideone.com/fdyQW). What version of VC++ are you using? (And the error message definitely implies that you changed my code somehow, as it's complaining about `Outer<T>::Inner<bool>::count` rather than `Outer<bool>::Inner<bool>::count`.)

Comment: Using Visual studio 11 Beta platform toolseet V110 :)

Comment: @codekiddy : I don't have that installed, sorry. Either way, the code shown here is correct; I suspect you did modify it somehow. ;-]

Comment: No I didn't modify the code, It may be a bug in VS Beta 11, I'm going to download VS 2010 now and test it cos I wanna learn that. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To get one static member per Inner template class instance you can as an alternative use a separate template class.

```
template<typename T>
class Outer 
{
public:
    template<typename U>
    class Inner 
    {
    };
};

template <typename T>
struct InnerStatic
{
  static int count;
};

template <typename T>
int InnerStatic<T>::count = 4;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  std::cout << InnerStatic<Outer<int>::Inner<int>>::count << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```