# Declare static object of a nested class template

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to declare a static object of a nested class template inside the first class template, like so:

```
template <typename... a_t>
class A {
private:
    template <typename... b_t>
    class B {

    };

    static B<a_t...> b;
};
```

This is the code I'd expect would make this work, but causes compilation errors, despite [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437298/initializing-static-member-of-nested-templated-class-during-nested-template-spec), which works for non-templated members inside the second class template:

```
template <typename... a_t>
template <typename... b_t>
A<a_t...>::B<b_t...> A<a_t...>::b; //incorrect?
```

What is the correct syntax that would accomplish this?

Comment: The first example compiles for GCC 4.8, but not the second block of code because you've made a mistake: You only need *one* template declaration and `::B<b_t...>` should be `::B<a_t....>`.

Comment: As @0x499602D2 is answering it: template <typename... a_t> A<a_t...>::B<a_t...> A<a_t...>::b;

Comment: @0x499602D2 This is what I get when I do that: "warning C4346: 'A<a_t...>::?$B@$$W$Ra_t@BAAB@' : dependent name is not a type," "error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'A<a_t...>::b'"

Comment: @NmdMystery Visual Studio doesn't fully support variadic templates (or C++11 for that matter). Try compiling the same code using just one template parameter for each class and see if it works. (i.e `template<class T> struct A {...};`)

Comment: @0x499602D2 That causes the same error, though you're right about visual studio having problems with variadics :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot **typename** keyword:

```
template <typename... a_t>
typename A<a_t...>::B<a_t...> A<a_t...>::b;
```

Comment: I'll make sure this works when I get back to VC++ (in case it seems like I abandoned the question).